# How to insert 13 million records with selected columns of a table to another existing table?

Tags: mysql

I've two tables one is the main table having data and I want to insert data from another existing table having about 13 million records. I'm using the query to insert from another table i.e.

```
insert into table1 ( column1, col2 ...) select col1, col2... from table2;
```

But, unfortunately the query fails as lock wait timeout comes Error 1205.

What is the best way to do it in least time without timeout.

Comment: Could you try giving the `select col1...` a limit of 1,000,000 and see if it's able to do it. If that works, then maybe try 2,000,000+ until you finish inserting all of the records.

Comment: I've tried to insert 1 million rows and it works but that was another table. Don't you think ordering and limiting will be slower

Comment: guidelines of programming: : First get it working, if it is too slow, measure it. It is not always obvious where the bottlenecks are.

Comment: You are right. I'm trying =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a primary key on table2, then you can use that for ordering and inserting in batches:

```
insert into table1 ( column1, col2 ...)
    select col1, col2...
    from table2
    order by <primary key>
    limit 0, 100000
```

Then repeat this for additional values.  (Of course, the 100,000 is arbitrary.  A larger value might work.  A smaller value might be necessary.)

Another possibility is to remove all indexes and insert triggers from `table1`, try the insert without them, and then add them back after the new data is in the table.

Comment: don't you think that will slow down the process .